# When to use "The" in book titles

Tags: grammar

When should you use "the" in book titles?

For example "The Lord of The Rings" is about that one lord of those rings.

So just in terms of grammar, are both "The Lords of the Rings" and "Lords of the Rings" correct? In this case I imagine the latter implies there are a bunch of lords of the rings. If I'm wrong please correct me, thanks.

Comment: It's Lord not Lords; there's no plural in the title (ever), so why should there be a bunch of lords of the rings?

Comment: I'm talking about grammar, not Tolkien's work. chasly from UK had answered my question before your comment.

Comment: When you're the author, you can pick whatever title you want.

Comment: The author determines the book title including whether there is "the" or not. @HotLicks is right. Here's another example. T.S. Eliot wrote the book "Four Quartets". It is not "The Four Quartets". Same applies with Tolkien's book. The title is "The Lord of the Rings". If you were Tolkien and you wanted to call it "The Lords of the Rings" or even "Lords of the Rings" that would be okay too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The Lords of the Rings" is grammatically correct. It refers to a particular group of lords. There is a nuance of history about it that suggests the people involved have all been accounted for in the title. Similarly a book called "The Kings and Queens of England" would be expected to cover every monarch up to the time of publication.

"Lords of the Rings" is also correct. As a title it is less well-defined than the one with a definite article. It could mean the same as the above but it may refer to a more fluid or partial situation.

There is no strict rule for titles that I am aware of  - it's up to the author.